# TestRunConfig does not copy App.config file

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testrunconfig

Hello
I have a UnitTest project, and I added multiple App.config files (never copied to the output directory). I have created runtestconfig files for different configuration I need.

```
<DeploymentItem filename="Config01\App.config" />
```

Each time I run the project using Mstest

```
mstest.exe /runconfig:Config01.testrunconfig /testcontainer:MyTests.dll
```

or using VS2008 active configuration, my tests fail.
In solution output directory the App.config file never gets copied.

This is a test ex:

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestAge()
  {
     string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["age"];
     Assert.AreEqual(value, "21");
  }
```

and this is the error:`Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<(null)>. Actual:<21>.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem using xml files instead of App.config. Now if I change the configuration and I run the tests both in VS or command line using MSTest I get the expected results.
It seems it does not work using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to read data from App.config files.